# What does "U.t.c." stand for in the context of a math proof?

Tags: proof-writing

What does "U.t.c." stand for in the context of a math proof? This abbreviation appears at the start of some (but not all) proofs in Desoer and Vidyasagar.

"U.t.c." isn't searchable online (conflicts with *temps universel coordonné*), and isn't on Wikipedia's list of mathematical abbreviations.

Comment: Under this/that/these condition(s)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coming from Google Book's preview of Feedback Systems (which I assume is the book you reference), there is a "note to the reader" section in the front of the book.  Near the bottom of that page:

> For convenience the abbreviations u.t.c. for "under these conditions" and s.t. for "so that" are used throughout.

Comment: Note: I'd also accept this as a duplicate of something like "best practices for reaching math textbooks". I only started trying to learn from books recently. I checked the table of symbols (where I expected to find it), but missed "note to the reader" because I thought this just a preface.

Comment: Question: This question was downvoted; Would it be best for the community if I delete it?